# Checking if a certain object in the list is this kind of class

Tags: java

I want to check if an object in the list is a certain type of class

i want my method to be something like

```
public <T> MyCustomObject get (Class<T>clz){
List<SomeObject> list= getList();

for(SomeObject o : list){

   if o is the same class as clz, or o is a child of clz return it
}


}
```

and call the method like this

```
MyCustomObject o =  get(MyCustomObjectVeryFarDescendant.class);
```

what would my comparison clause look like ?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: You're going to need to use the `getClass()` method on `SomeObject o`. The same with `T`. And that is as much as you're getting from me.

Comment: yes, i tried o.class == clz, and for a descendant it returns false

Comment: Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [isInstance(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) is what you're looking for:

```
public <T> MyCustomObject get (Class<T>clz){
   List<SomeObjects> list= getList();

   for(SomeObject o : list){
      if (clz.isInstance(o)) {
          return (T) o;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This operator is used only for checking `"object reference variables"`. This operator checks the type of `"object reference variable "` and return "true" if it is of the provided type.

```
if (objectReference instanceof type)
```

In this syntax, `"objectReference"` is the object name and `"type"` is the name of object type for checking it's type. The operator checks whether the object is of a particular type(class type or interface type).

For Example :

```
Car c = new Car();
boolean result = c instanceof Car;
```

This will return 'true' and store 'true' to boolean variable 'result'

To know more about instanceOf operator refer

[What is instanceof operator](http://www.guruzon.com/1/java-basics/operators/use-of-instanceof-operators-with-example)

also

[instanceof operator](http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator)

Comment: That won't work to test if an object is an instance of a Class instance passed as argument.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do

```
if(o instanceof MyCustomObjectVeryFarDescendant){
   return o;
}
```

It will return o if o is an instance of `MyCustomObjectVeryFarDescendant` or any of it's subclass.

Comment: for a boolean yes or no solution you could use the above by simply ---- return o instanceof MyCustomObject;

Comment: I want to decouple it - this is why i do not want this class to know there is a "very far descendant"

Comment: But that won't work with a Class instance passed as argument. You can't do `o instanceof clz`